# Require Package Options

Tags: packages, kvoptions

I would like to create a sty file that sources another custom sty file. I have all files in a directory `/home/Desktop/Common/Latex/LatexSetup`. I have tried the following code, which fails.

```
\RequirePackage[kvoptions]
\DeclareStringOption[/home/Desktop/Common/Latex/LatexSetup]{setupfolder}[/home/Desktop/Common/Latex/LatexSetup]
\ProcessOptions\relax

\RequirePackage{\setupfolder/Latex_Defs}
```

The reason I don't want to include `Latex_Defs` is because I use this in multiple packages. My end goal is to have others be able to change this folder if they are using it somewhere else.

Comment: The argument of `\RequirePackage` should never be a filepath, the fact that that sometimes works is an accident of the implementation, it should just be the package name.

Comment: Just put `Setup.sty` in your tex input path so (like `kvoptions.sty` can be referenced by name from any directory.

Comment: I do no understand your second comment. If I eliminate the filepath, then I get the error `! LaTeX Error: File 'ASetup.sty' not found.`

Comment: you would get the same error from `\usepackage{graphicx}` if `graphicx.sty` was not installed in the right place, the solution is not to use `\usepackage{/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphicx}`

Comment: You should create a symlink (or a hard link, or a copy) of your file into your local texmf (that's what David Carlisle is trying to say).

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te

Comment: I created the texmf folder, and have got everything working now. Thank you both.